# Modifying Sphinx Python theme 'Read the Docs' to have: next and previous buttons

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm running on Ubuntu
http://missionimpossible3000.org/

I want to add a "next" and "previous" button on the bottom of my page.

Can anyone help me figure out what file I have to edit?

Where is the file located?

And what to type in that file?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I simply had to create a new page and the buttons appeared automatically.